# Unable to show menu icons in appbar

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show search icon in app bar for implementing search functionality.I have created menu resource file and inflate that in **MainActivity** but  unable to see search icon.

Below is my code:

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
     android:id="@+id/search"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
     android:title="Item"
     app:showAsAction="always"
     app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

}

  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu)
    return true
  }
}
```

Someone let me know why icon is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` add this:

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.IdentifierOfYourToolBarInYourMainActivityXML)
```